# having trouble Converting procedural JavaScript to a more OOP code version

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, dom

I currently have built an add more system to generate more fields for users in a form and then also to check in query string if form fails. However it is done in a more procedural way in that each version is its own which leads me to having the similar code duplicated like 5 times (one for each version and for each function) and was wondering if you could help me convert it to more of a OOP way so it is only one set code to make it easier to run on my system and thus not making me run so much code and a more streamlined code

I have tried to make it somewhat OOP but i keep getting errors as I'm not very good at the JavaScript or OOP I got it to work basic JavaScript but that means i have so many extra lines of codes

So Here is the base code which works however it is like shown it will be duplicated 3 more times after these ones

```
<script>
<!-- MORE BIKES -->
var max_fields_morebikes = 4;
var wrapper_bike = $("#currentbikes");
var add_button_morebikes = $("#morebikes");
var counter_bikes = 1;

<!-- add and delete for morebikes -->
$(add_button_morebikes).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter_bikes < max_fields_morebikes) {
        counter_bikes++;
        $(wrapper_bike).append('<div class="morebikesadd"><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" placeholder="Current Bikes" ><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
        //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
});
$(wrapper_bike).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    counter_bikes--;
});
</script>
```

and also have versions where there is adding 2 sets of inputs

```
<script>
<!-- RACES HISTORY -->
var max_fields_racehist = 5;
var wrapper_racehist = $("#racinghistoryresults");
var add_button_racehist = $("#moreracehist");
var counter_racehist = 1;

<!-- add and delete for RaceHistory -->
$(add_button_racehist).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter_racehist < max_fields_racehist) {
        counter_racehist++;
        $(wrapper_racehist).append('<div style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="text" name="racehist[]" class="racehist addmoreracehistory" placeholder="Race History">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="results[]" class="results addmorementionableresults" placeholder="Mentionable Results">&nbsp;<button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
        //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
});
$(wrapper_racehist).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    counter_racehist--;
});
</script>
```

This is the method I tried for at least if there is one input

```
<button type="button" onclick="return addMoreRows(5,1, 'morebikesadd', 'currentbike','currentbikesadd','Current Bike', 'delete')"> Add More</button>
<script>
 function addMoreRows(numFields, maxCounter, addMoreClass, inputName, inputClass, placeHolderName,buttonClass){
        var max_fields = numFields;
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        var counter = maxCounter;

        if (counter < max_fields) {
            counter++;
            wrapper.appendChild('<div class="' + addMoreClass + '"><input type="text" name="'+ inputName +'[]" class="'+ inputClass +'" placeholder="'+ placeHolderName +'"><button class="'+ buttonClass +'"> Delete </button></div>');
        }
        else {
            alert('You Have Reached the limits')
        }

    }
</script>
```

I want to know if possible how i can combine it so that it will just take in the values i put into and work so i only need 1 maybe 2 functions (depends if it can combine the only 1 inputs and 2 inputs) so that I can do `onclick=" addMoreRows(values,values,etc)"` so that can be done easier

Comment: Do you want to optimize `addMorRows` only?

Comment: @AdnanSharif yea, so the original is above with a bit of Jquery, i would like to know how to convert it to `addMoreRows` so like if that is correctly done from the one above and then yeah optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you want want to code such as you don't need to write same type of functions multiple time.

In your code there are are two type: **bikes** and **raceHistory**. They have similar properties such as `maxLimit`, `currentCount`, `selector` and html for new element.
So, you can make an `object` like the following:

```
var itemTypes = {
    bike:{
        maxLimit: 4,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#currentbikes',
        newElement: '<div class="morebikesadd"><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" placeholder="Current Bikes" ><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'
    },
    raceHistory:{
        maxLimit: 5,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#racinghistoryresults',
        newElement: '<div style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="text" name="racehist[]" class="racehist addmoreracehistory" placeholder="Race History">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="results[]" class="results addmorementionableresults" placeholder="Mentionable Results">&nbsp;<button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'
    }
}
```

From you html, just send your **type** as an argument for your `addMoreRows()` function, for example, for `bike` use following:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="return addMoreRows('bike')"> Add More Bike</button>
```

OR use the following for `raceHistory`

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addMoreRows('raceHistory')"> Add More Race History</button>
```

and handle from your `addMoreRows()` function like this

```
function addMoreRows(type){
    var item = itemTypes[type];
    if (item.currentCount < item.maxLimit) {
        item.currentCount++;
        $(item.selector).append(item.newElement);
    }
    else {
        alert('You Have Reached the limits')
    }
}
```

Hola! Everything is now generalized!

If you want to add another type, for example, `motorBike`, then just update your `itemTypes` Object like the following:

```
var itemTypes = {
    bike:{
        maxLimit: 4,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#currentbikes',
        newElement: '<div class="morebikesadd"><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" placeholder="Current Bikes" ><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'
    },
    raceHistory:{
        maxLimit: 5,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#racinghistoryresults',
        newElement: '<div style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="text" name="racehist[]" class="racehist addmoreracehistory" placeholder="Race History">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="results[]" class="results addmorementionableresults" placeholder="Mentionable Results">&nbsp;<button class="delete">Delete</button></div>'
    },
    motorBike:{
        maxLimit: 10,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#selectorformotorbike',
        newElement: '<div>Put your desired code for new element</div>'
    }
}
```

You don't need do anything in your `javascript` for new changes!

Here is the working code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="addMoreRows('raceHistory')"> Add More Race History</button>

<div id="racinghistoryresults">
</div>

<script>
var itemTypes = {
    bike:{
        maxLimit: 4,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#currentbikes',
        newElement: '<div class="morebikesadd"><input type="text" name="currentbike[]" class="currentbikesadd" placeholder="Current Bikes" ><button class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this, \'bike\')">Delete</button></div>'
    },
    raceHistory:{
        maxLimit: 5,
        currentCount: 1,
        selector: '#racinghistoryresults',
        newElement: '<div style=" margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="text" name="racehist[]" class="racehist addmoreracehistory" placeholder="Race History">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="results[]" class="results addmorementionableresults" placeholder="Mentionable Results">&nbsp;<button class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this, \'raceHistory\')">Delete</button></div>'
    }
}

function addMoreRows(type){
    var item = itemTypes[type];
    if (item.currentCount < item.maxLimit) {
        item.currentCount++;
        $(item.selector).append(item.newElement);
    }
    else {
        alert('You Have Reached the limits')
    }
}

function deleteRow(event, type){
  $(event).parent('div').remove();
  itemTypes[type].currentCount--;
};
</script>
```

Hope, this helps you!

Comment: Yes @adnan Sharif you have taken my shitty long version of the code and made it perfect and simple <3 man

Comment: Can I ask at the moment you have removed the Delete functionality from the delete button? can i ask how i would re-add it to the code

Comment: @Meitie I have updated my answer and added delete functionality also. See how I added `deleteRow()` function on `newElement` object. Thanks!

Comment: do you know anywhere or places that i can learn some tutorials into better javascript knowledge and understanding cause i have other places in my code that i would like to do this as it seems to load quicker for me when it is like this also it saves space

Comment: unless i could post another question and link you to here from here or possibly put it in a jsfiddle so you could see what im doing and how to change it to neater code?

Comment: Dear @Meitie you will get most resource link regarding [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) from these links. Thanks!